# How to generate multiple jar files from multi-module Spring Boot application with use of maven goal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Having a Spring Boot project with three modules "mod1", "mod2", "mod3" how can I structure (and which plugins should I use) my four pom.xml files (including the one from parent directory) to build my project in a following way:
I want to run maven goal against this multi module project and as a result I want to have:
one jar (which will be packaged from mod1 and mod2) in parent's target directory and
one jar in mod3's target directory which will be a fat jar (here I assume I should use maven shade plugin) generated only from mod3 module and it's dependencies.

To summarize. Expected outcome is:
mod1 + mod2 → parent.jar
mod3 → mod3fatjar.jar

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a multi module project is the correct way to go.

```
+-- root
     +-- pom.xml
     +-- mod1
     !    +-- pom.xml
     +-- mod2
     !    +-- pom.xml
     +-- mod3
          +-- pom.xml
```

In the root pom defining the list of modules. Using the dependencyManagement for doing the following

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      .
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

The `${spring.boot.version}`represents the version of spring boot you would like to use.
In the modules for example `mod1` and `mod2` you can define deps you need. In the `mod3` you define usually the main application which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and you should use the [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) to package your final application and do *not* use things like maven-shade-plugin nor can you create the jar within the root target directory which does not make sense. The resulting executable jar (your spring boot app) will be generated in the `mod3` `target` directory...

Very important thing is that you should be aware of is to define all plugins in the `root` pom via `pluginManagement`.

And finally you can call `mvn verify` from the root location.